# Раздел "Исследования"

Tags: предложение, хэшкод

В старом добром HashCode (ru.SO до присоединения к SO) был раздел "Исследования", где каждый мог написать своего рода статью и получить комментарии и советы от сообщества. Но после присоединения в SO этот раздел то ли пропал, то ли я его не виду. Будет ли восстановлен такой формат для обменом знаний?